# how can I filter the search in linux

Tags: linux, search, filter

I have a datafile  that looks like this: and sometimes some of them start with "key M###" (### stands for any number), how can I filter my search so that only those records containing the "M" will appear??

```
> dip binary_data_file.df | tail
key K701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key K701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key M701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key K701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key K701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key K701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key K701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key K701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key K701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key M701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the data to `grep` for filtering. Something like below -

```
            cat datafile.txt | grep "M[0-9]*"|less
```

Answer (score 0):

**file.txt:**

```
key K701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key K701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key M701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key K701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key K701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key K701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key K701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key K701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key K701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key M701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
```

Use `grep`:

```
$ grep -E 'M[0-9]{3}' file.txt
```

or use `egrep`:

```
$ egrep 'M[0-9]{3}' file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
key M701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
key M701, datafile binary_data_file.df, prt 0000000
```